# How to change mat-checkbox background-color in CSS3 ? Angular6

Tags: css, angular-material, angular6

I need change background with mat-ripple use class="matCheckboxClass"

HTML:

```
<mat-checkbox class="matCheckboxClass"></mat-checkbox>
```

CSS3:

```
.matCheckboxClass .mat-checkbox-checked
.mat-accent.mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent 
.mat-checkbox-background {
background-color: rgb(27, 142, 241) !important;
}

.matCheckboxClass .mat-ripple-element  {
 background: rgba(27, 142, 241, .4) !important;
 }
```

**Note: ::ng-deep will change all mat-checkbox I need change specific mat-checkbox.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can try this:

:host /deep/{
    .matCheckboxClass .mat-checkbox-checked
    .mat-accent.mat-checkbox-background, .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent 
    .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: rgb(27, 142, 241) !important;
}

 .matCheckboxClass .mat-ripple-element  {
     background: rgba(27, 142, 241, .4) !important;
  }
}
```